# Conexion a servidor remoto (Alojado a Hostgator) se cae después de 1 minuto

Tags: java, mysql

estoy realizando una conexión a un servidor remoto (por medio de hostinguer) con mi programa hecho en java, el problema con esto que, cada vez que entro y por ejemplo cargo una tabla después de 1 minuto transcurrido al querer realizar otra consulta (cargar de nuevo la tabla por ejemplo) el servidor se cae y tienes que volver a realizar la consulta para que pueda efectuarse. Al caer la conexión me tira estos errores.[![Error cuando se desconecta de la base][1]][1]
Loading class `com.mysql.jdbc.Driver'. This is deprecated. The new driver class is` com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver'. The driver is automatically registered via the SPI and manual loading of the driver class is generally unnecessary.
Fri Feb 12 22:51:05 COT 2021 WARN: Establishing SSL connection without server's identity verification is not recommended. According to MySQL 5.5.45+, 5.6.26+ and 5.7.6+ requirements SSL connection must be established by default if explicit option isn't set. For compliance with existing applications not using SSL the verifyServerCertificate property is set to 'false'. You need either to explicitly disable SSL by setting useSSL=false, or set useSSL=true and provide truststore for server certificate verification.
CONEXION EXITOSA

[1]: [https://i.stack.imgur.com/PyYes.jpg![introducir](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PyYes.jpg!%5Bintroducir) la descripción de la imagen aquí](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b014f.jpg)

Revise con un programa que gestiona la actividad de la conexión y manda el comando sleep después de unos minutos y como mencioné antes ya añadí lo que pide

Comment: Bienvenido a [es.so]. Por favor, edita tu pregunta y agrega el mensaje de error  _como texto_. En imagen es prácticamente ilegible. Lee [ask].

Comment: El mensaje de error es bastante descriptivo, ¿has hecho algo para corregir lo que te está diciendo? Sé que está en inglés, pero si vas a programar, tendrás que ir empezando a aprender a leer mensajes de error en inglés: *Establishing SSL connection without server's identity verification is not recommended.* ... *You need either to explicitly disable SSL by setting useSSL=false, or set useSSL=true and provide truststore for server certificate verification* ... etc. Esa podría ser la causa del error (o no). La BD podría estarse desconectado por un problema de seguridad.

Comment: Si, he añadido el comando ?useSSL=false al final de mi conexión para desactivar eso, como lo menciona el programa y sin embargo después de 2 minutos cae la conexión y ya no puedo hacer consultas y me tira el error mostrado

jdbc:mysql://host:port/database?useSSL=false (Use este formato)